# View Position In Layout

Tags: java, android

Loading class (View):

```
public class Loading extends View {

    private long movieStart;
    private Movie movie;

    public Loading(Context context, InputStream inputStream) {
            super(context);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if(movieStart == 0)
            movieStart = now;
        final int relTime = (int)((now - movieStart) % movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas, 100, 100);
        this.invalidate();
    }

}
```

Activity onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
       inputStream = getAssets().open("loading.gif");
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Loading loading = new Loading(this, inputStream);
    setContentView(loading);
}
```

I want to set the view in center of the device layout. Like in XML layout, that we can set android:layout_centerHorizontal="true". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set LayoutParams for the View.  What I would do is put your custom view in a container, for example a FrameLayout.  Then, create your view and set the FrameLayout.LayoutParams for your View with gravity set to CENTER_HORIZONTAL.  It'll look something like this

```
FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(context);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams flParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
);

Loading loading = new Loading(this, inputStream);
loading.setLayoutParams(flParams);
frame.addView(loading);
setContentView(frame);
```

You may want to configure the FrameLayout to get it to display how you want.

Here's the documentation for the LayoutParams constructor I'd use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#FrameLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20int%29

It's important to remember that each of the Views that extend ViewParent have their own LayoutParams class, so, for example, if you wanted to use a LinearLayout instead of a FrameLayout, you'd use LinearLayout.LayoutParams.  Different types of Params have different constructor options, so you can play around with it and find which is best for you.  Good luck.

Comment: In this part -> FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(context); Where is context from?

Comment: context is the Context for the current instance of your activity, usually gotten with the keyword `this`.  For example, if your Activity is called TestActivity, your context would be `TestActivity.this`

Comment: Actually I do it, but when I run it ... the emulator shows a black page!

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add loading to the frame.  I've edited my code snippet.

Comment: I do it. I can watch it, but the view still in its position!

Comment: Maybe try setting the width and height in the LayoutParams to FILL_PARENT?